# Create a jenkins Job for TestNG tests

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I need help to configure a freestyle job for maven test execution.

I have a test framework with TestNG tests and need to configure job for executing the testsuite xml files in it. please tell me the maven command that i need to use to execute those suite files

Comment: What have you tried? Did you search the same before asking? Show us some code, error, exception etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide minimal, useful code that can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly its better to configure Maven project rather than a Freestyle project(For Maven project you need "Maven Integration Plugin")

Now include compiler and surefire plugins in your pom.xml file under build tag. If there is no build tag add it(Since you have not shown your pom.xml code)

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.2</version>
 <configuration>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.12</version>
 <inherited>true</inherited>
 <configuration>
  <forkMode>never</forkMode>
  <suiteXmlFiles>
   <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
  </suiteXmlFiles>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

[Then on your Jenkins homepage. Create new item under maven build. Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwiYa.jpg)

[Then in your project configuration enter below values. Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX5pl.jpg)

Fill up any remaining information you want(Email etc)

Now go to your newly created project and Build. :)

Comment: Its working but the jenkins build shows as Passed eventhough there is failures in Test. Please advise

Comment: Here there are 2 scenarios:

1. When your build passes and with that, your all testcases, on your console output it will show "Build Success" and "FINISHED: SUCCESS".
2. When your build passes but some of your testcases fail, in that case on your console output it will show "Build Success" but "FINISHED: UNSTABLE". :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using  maven-surefire-plugin.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

After adding the plugin. Any of the following commands will run your tests

- mvn test
- mvn package
- mvn verify
- mvn install